# PowerPoint for Mac Office 2011 Doesn't Save Hyperlinks to PDF?

Tags: mac, pdf, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, office-for-mac

Related to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/306316/mac-office-powerpoint-save-as-pdf-with-hyperlinks) without an answer, I'm using the latest PowerPoint for Mac (14.2.3) but when I save a PPTX as a PDF the links are gone. Is there some trick to getting them to remain?

Links aren't clickable in Mac Preview or PDF.js inside Firefox, however Chrome apparently creates links where it thinks they should exist because it's built-in reader will show the URL as a link.

Just created a blank PowerPoint and linked to 'http://www.google.com' to test and all the above holds true, only clickable in Chrome's viewer.

Note: Tried this with the same PPTX on Windows Office 2010 and the links save to PDF fine so it doesn't appear to be an issue with my file

Answer (score 1):

Neither PowerPoint 2011 nor Word 2011 exports hyperlinks when saving as PDF.  You'll need their corresponding Windows versions to export PDFs with hyperlinks.

Some URLs appears to be clickable because they are recognized by the PDF renderer and does not have the hyperlink embedded in the document.